# How can I fix “Error: Failure during raster IO”?

Tags: r, r-raster

I'm trying to working with 12 high resolution LANDSAT images at 30m resolution (1.4 Gb per image) as covariates in a species distribution model. 
But I get the following error: `“Error: Failure during raster IO”` when extracting values from my raster stack.

```
library(raster)
preds <- suppressWarnings( raster::stack(files))
envtrain <- extract(preds, train)
```

I read some suggestion to reduce the images area, but it's not good for me.

Answer (score 2):

This almost certainly means that your raster file is corrupted. Try downloading it again. And why do you use `suppressWarnings`. Remove that and look at the warnings... (and show them to us!)